# Error when calling an Oracle stored procedure though Java code

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, callable-statement

I am calling a PL/SQL procedure in a Java application to update a database entry.

```
Connection connection = null;
CallableStatement preparedCall = null;
Integer result = 0;
preparedCall = connection.prepareCall("{ call ? := pkg_temp.update_data(?, ?)}");
preparedCall.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.INTEGER);
preparedCall.setString(2, variable1);
preparedCall.setString(3, cariable2);
result = preparedCall.executeUpdate();
```

But I am getting the below error at executeUpdate()

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 11:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ; indicator
ORA-06550: line 1, column 51:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
. ( ) , * % & - + / at mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)>
and or || multiset
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:=` is wrong and the placeholder for return parameter must be listed *before* the `call` keyword ([as documented in the JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html)):

```
connection.prepareCall("{?= call pkg_temp.update_data(?, ?)}");
```

Comment: thanks for the suggettion. But changing to this syntax gave this error Severe:   java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Well, that is an error _inside_ your stored procedure. You are either passing the wrong type or your procedure is relying on the evil implicit data type conversion. In either case this can't be answered without seeing the complete code for the procedure

Comment: thank you...I think I found the problem. The return type of my procedure is boolean. But here I am registering it to Integer. However, registering the out parameter to OracleTypes.BOOLEAN won't work. What should I do for that?